# Counting from & to specific dates & times on a spreadsheet - mostly done, but some bugs

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I wanted to make a spreadsheet that I could enter a date & time and calculate how much time (in years/dates/months/weeks/hours/minutes/seconds...)

I kept expanding on it. it serves very little functional purpose but it was fun... here is the file...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19WJ7ld-SN6kWfCec94NDu5yEk8Md04j9i_O7C4KtkYw/edit?usp=sharing

Some things I need help with

- my month calculator doesn't seem to work... for the future? (red on sample)
- my time to/from calculator seems to add 12 hours? i'm guessing I need to do it a different way... column f
- for calculators on specific days of every year (e.g. enter a birthday, and if you open the file in 2020 or 2024 i want it to show days to/from that same year...)

thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*Show method is based on data, shared through Google sheet.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `M2`:

  ```
  =DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"y") &" years, "&DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"ym") &" months, " &DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"md") &" days"
  ```
- Formula in Cell `N2`:

  ```
  =INT((NOW()-L2)*24) &" Hrs, " & INT((NOW()-L2)*24*60)&" Min, " & INT((NOW()-L2)*24*60*60)& " Seco"
  ```
- Formula in Cell `O2`:

  `=DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"Y")`
- Formula in Cell `P2`:

  `=DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"m")`
- Formula in Cell `Q2`:

  `=CEILING.MATH(DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"D")/7,1)`
- Formula in Cell `R2`:

  `=DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"d")`
- Formula in Cell `S2`:

  `=INT((NOW()-L2)*24)`
- Formula in Cell `T2`:

  `=INT((NOW()-L2)*24*60)`
- Formula in Cell `U2`:

  `=INT((NOW()-L2)*24*60*60)`

**N.B.**

- Cell `L3`, has Bith date & Time of Dr. Martin Luther king Jr.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, those formulas don't seem to work better or address the issue in mine, but interesting :) thanks for trying!

Comment: @Korgun,,, no issue,, I've tried almost what has been solved in attached google sheet,,, if possible just write which one is different !