# Excel: total of time difference formatted in months, days, hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I need an Excel Ninja. I want to format a cell in Excel so the total time difference is formatted in months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds. Right now, I don't know how to add "months" into formatting. I use "days, hours, minutes and seconds" but the total time difference is more than 31 days.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

E.g.: time difference between 21 Oct 2019 12:43 and 26 Nov 2019 13:45 displayed as months, days, hours, minutes, seconds. So the result should show like: 1 month 5 days 1 hrs 2 min 0 sec

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser [Check this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1560764/counting-from-to-specific-dates-times-on-a-spreadsheet-mostly-done-but-so/1560862#1560862) recently I've solves similar issue ☺

Comment: Since `months` is not a fixed duration, what is **your** rule for converting days to months?

Answer (score 1):

*You may use this:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `X1`:

  ```
  =INT(V3-V1) & " days, " & HOUR(V3-V1) & " hours, " & MINUTE(V3-V1) & " minutes and " & SECOND(V3-V1) & " seconds"
  ```

---

**:Edited:**

[image]

*If you want to calculate total days along with Hours, Minutes & Seconds between two DateTime stamps then use this formula in cell `X3`*

```
 =INT(V3-V1) & " days, " & INT((V3-V1)*24) &" Hrs, " & INT((V3-V1)*24*60)&" Min, " & INT((V3-V1)*24*60*60)& " Sec"
```

---

**:Edited 2:**

[image]

- Formula in cell `X16`:

  ```
  =INT(V17-V16) & " days, " & HOUR(V17-V16) & " hours, " & MINUTE(V17-V16) & " minutes and " & SECOND(V17-V16) & " seconds"
  ```

---

**:Edited 3:**

[image]

- Formula in cell `X18`:

  ```
  =DATEDIF(V16,V17,"y") &" years, "&DATEDIF(V16,V17,"ym") &" months, " &DATEDIF(V16,V17,"md") &" days"  & HOUR(V17-V16) & " hours, " & MINUTE(V17-V16) & " minutes and " & SECOND(V17-V16) & " seconds"
  ```

**N.B.** *Formula in `X16` calculates 36 Days is 1 month + 5 Days.*

- If Dates are `01-Oct-20 12:43 PM` & `02-Nov-20 01:45 PM`, formula in
  X16 gets `32 Days, 1 Hours, 2 minutes and 0 Secs`. And in X18, you
  get `0 Years, 1 Month, 1 Days, 1 hours, 2 Minutes & 0 Secs`.

*You may adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Comment: thanks for your reply. What happens if the time difference is more than 31 days?

Comment: @BigAl, the show formula will find the difference even is more than 31 days like if start DateTime is `06/01/20 08:30 AM` and End DateTIme is `07/18/20 15:30 PM`. If U are looking for total hours to be calculated between 2 Dates then check the link I've added as comments.

Comment: @BigAl, now check the edited part of my post.

Comment: my excel rejects formula: =DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"y") &" years, "&DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"ym") &" months, " &DATEDIF(L2,NOW(),"md") &" days"

Comment: @BigAl, what error U are getting and check the dates I've written in L2, is Date Time in past ! I've attached screen shots , check it.

Comment: it doesn't make sense. The result in my case is 5 days, 121 Hrs, 7261 Min, 435694 Sec.Seconds exceeding 60 should turn to minutes, minutes over 60 turn into hours, etc.

Comment: What is Date Time is L2 ,, write and let me test !!

Comment: time difference between 21 Oct 2019 12:43 and 26 Nov 2019 13:45 displayed as months, days, hours, minutes, seconds. So the result should show like: 1 month 5 days 1 hrs 2 min 0 sec

Comment: @BigAl the DATEDIF find Years ,, Months & Days not time,,, check EDited part I've posted new formula with explanation too.

Comment: @BigAl ,, Formula in X1 find Days and the real time difference but in X3 the formula find Days as well as total Hrs,, Minutes,,, for 17 days time span. U may use either of ,,, !

Comment: again, time difference is longer than 31 days. Can you post the solution to my example? E.g.: time difference between 21 Oct 2019 12:43 and 26 Nov 2019 13:45 displayed as months, days, hours, minutes, seconds. So the result should show like: 1 month 5 days 1 hrs 2 min 0 sec

Comment: @BigAl,, check edited 2 ,,, got the correct  difference,,, calculate Days between 21 Oct 2019 & 26 Nov 2019  ,,  will get 36 days,, how u are getting 5 days !!

Comment: @BigAl,, now check Edited 3,,, Ive use combination of Formula find every thing ,,, hope now U get the way formula works !!